# Installing Docker in Ubuntu on Windows 10 : Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-10

I am trying to install Docker in Ubuntu on Windows 10 using script below but then I try to run Docker as service `service docker start` the Docker does not starts and I find an error in docker.log. I was using the same installation instruction on plain Ubuntu machine and had no problem running docker.

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE: iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
 (exit status 1))
```

Installation script

```
# Update the apt package list.
sudo apt-get update -y

# Install Docker's package dependencies.
sudo apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Download and add Docker's official public PGP key.
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Verify the fingerprint.
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

# Add the `stable` channel's Docker upstream repository.
#
# If you want to live on the edge, you can change "stable" below to "test" or
# "nightly". I highly recommend sticking with stable!
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

# Update the apt package list (for the new apt repo).
sudo apt-get update -y

# Install the latest version of Docker CE.
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

# Allow your user to access the Docker CLI without needing root access.
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and here is what I found out.
It currently isn't possible to run docker in WSL. The work around is

- Update the apt package with:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS with:
  `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common`
- Add docker's GPG key:
  `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
- Set up a stable repository with:
  `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
- Update the apt package again:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install docker DCE:
  `sudo apt-get install docker-ce`
- Then add this command which notifies docker of the host to communicate:
  `echo "export DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375" >> ~/.bash_profile`
- Restart your vscode
- Install docker desktop and go to your settings and check the "Expose daemon tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS".

With this, I was able to run docker in WSL(ubuntu). Hope it helps.

credit: https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4

Answer (score 1):

Running Docker in WSL is not currently possible. You will have to install [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) in Windows. Then you can install the Docker CLI in WSL and use docker from there

If you have enabled the WSL2 preview feature you can install [Docker Desktop in WSL 2 mode](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), which will give much better performance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. This is a great guide
https://tjisblogging.blogspot.com/2022/05/install-docker-on-windows-11-with-wsl.html

The below is the second on the IP table error that can happen

If it is Ubuntu 22.04, then it might have an issue with the iptables version. When you are checking the status, it might still show up not running. If that is the case, make sure to switch the iptables to legacy.

Run the below command to change the default iptables version.

sudo update-alternatives --config iptables

switch ip tables

Select the iptables-legacy by entering option 1. Then hit enter.